# Flask error handling ignored by JSON parse failure

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm working with Flask/Flask-RESTPlus to create a JSON-based REST API and as such I want to convert any errors from the server into the JSON format used. For whatever reason, the code I'm using doesn't seem to catch JSON decoding errors and instead outputs them directly with this response:

```
{
    "message": "Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"
}
```

From what I understand of Flask this should have come through as:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "message": "Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"
    }
}
```

I added a few debugging print statements and it's fairly clear to me that the response handler I added isn't actually catching anything since nothing gets output from the exception handler when a request with invalid JSON is made.

I've got the following code that replicates the issue:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, Response
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource
from werkzeug.exceptions import default_exceptions, HTTPException
import logging


def err_to_json(ex):
    logging.warning("error handler")
    logging.warning(ex)
    code = 500
    if isinstance(ex, HTTPException):
        code = ex.code

    return jsonify({"errors": {"message": str(ex)}}), code


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["HOST"] = "0.0.0.0"
app.config["PORT"] = 80
api = Api(app)


@api.route("/test")
class TestEndpoint(Resource):
    def post(self):
        data = request.get_json()
        logging.warning("data")
        logging.warning(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for ex in default_exceptions:
        app.register_error_handler(ex, err_to_json)

    app.run(port=8000, host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

This seems to be a slight adaptation of [the pattern recommended by the Flask library](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/errorhandling/). I've also tried directly handling the `JSONDecodeError`, but that made no difference either (`app.register_error_handler(json.JSONDecodeError, err_to_json)`).

Any idea why a request with invalid JSON causes a 400 error directly, instead of going through the error handler?

Comment: Are you sure the relevant exception is in `default_exceptions`?

Comment: @Barmar No, but it's not coming through as a 500 Internal Server Error if it wasn't caught, so I'm assuming that it's something that should be caught.

Comment: So the error is being caught, you're just not getting the result you expect? What you show looks like the value of the `error` property of the JSON result.

Comment: @Barmar That's what seems to be happening. I would agree, it seems like that is the error message but it's not being handled by my code.

Comment: Are you seeing the log messages from `logging.warning("error handler")`?

Comment: @Barmar No, I'm getting nothing from that the exception handler

Comment: But if you don't do any error handling you get a 500 error. How can removing a function that's never called possibly cause an error? Something really doesn't add up here.

Comment: @Barmar It does the same thing whether `register_error_handler()` is called or not. Which is what's really confusing me.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your earlier comment about the 500 error.

Comment: So it appears that Flask-RESTPlus is overriding the default Flask error handling, but that wasn't clear. You have to look in the [Error handling section](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/errors.html) of the Flask-RESTPlus documentation to find it. I've been able to catch a specific exception via `@api.errorhandler(<exception>)` but it's adding additional data to my response.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by Flask-RESTPlus overriding the Flask error handling code, as [documented here](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/errors.html).

In this case, I would theoretically need to set up a default error handler via the following, but it seems to be bugged, as per [this un-answered issue](https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/361):

```py
@api.errorhandler
def default_error_handler(err):
    return {"errors": {"message": str(err)}}, getattr(err, "code", 500)
```

Note that you also must set the `ERROR_INCLUDE_MESSAGE` config value to `False` if you want to avoid Flask-RESTPlus automatically adding in the `message` key again, resulting a response like the following:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "message": "400 Bad Request: Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"
    },
    "message": "400 Bad Request: Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"
}
```